# Digitally Pressing a keyfob button with a microcontroller

Tags: automotive, button, remote

For a project I'm working on, I need to press a car keyfob button with a microcontroller.  So I soldered two wires to the circuit thing on the keyfob so I can send signals to it.  This is what it looks like.

[image: KeyFob]

This is what I've tried so far:

1)  I've tried writing 3.3V to one of the wires I soldered to with a netduino 3.3V digital I/O pin.  I tried it by directly connecting it to the digital output port, and also with a 100 Ohm, 2.35kOhm, 4.7kOhm, and 9.4 kOhm resistors.

2)  I've tried shorting the cables to each other, and that didn't do anything either.

I also have made sure the microcontroller and the netduino had a common ground.

I have no idea why it doesn't work?  Especially when I short it.
When I take the rubber part of the keyfob,  and press it against the circuit it works every time.

EDIT:  I also know the keyfob isn't fried because when I power it with the netduino (3.3V) or the lithium battery (3V) and press the circuits with the rubber, it works just fine.  So the keyfob is still good.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you so much!

-Phil

Comment: check impedance across your soldered-on leads with battery removed from fob, when you press with the "rubber part." Shorting violet to blue should trigger the circuit; if directly shorting them doesn't work, try shorting for longer duration &/or shorting though a resistance to match whatever you can measure when using the original parts.

Comment: In addition to what @RobhercKV5ROB said, also make sure it works normally first - you may have damaged it by applying a voltage incorrectly during your tests.

Comment: How do you know it runs on 3V3? The 3V3 may have fried it already.

Comment: I know its not fried because when I press the buttons with the rubber it works just fine with 3.3V (netduino) or 3V (lithium battery).

Comment: @PhillipDavis Does it also work if you press the rubber to the ends of your soldered wires? If not, maybe there's a problem with the connection to the PCB.

Comment: @RogerRowland the more I think about it, the more I think the only problem is *duration* of the contact. Most keyfobs only succesfully xmit if you press the button for longer than, say, 0.1sec (or at least all of mine are that way). Considering that a GPIO pin being sent a '1' may only 'go high' for <=1us, that leaves about 5 krders of magnitude 'gap' to be filled. OP probably needs to hack the output to pull high/low (close the circuit) for >=0.25sec.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple switch hack that works with mp3 players uses a simple NPN transistor switch. I don't see why it shouldn't work with a keyfob.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

1) reverse engineer how the button is connected. For example if one side is connected to the ground of the lithium battery then you could simply place an NPN or NMOS across the button contacts. Connect grounds of key and netduino together. Maybe also replace the key's battery by connecting the +3 V to the 3.3 V from the netduino. Switch on/off the NPN or NMOS from the netduino via a 10 kohm resistor (not needed when using an NMOS).

1a) when one side of the button is connected to +3V use a PNP or a PMOS instead.

2) if it's not so clear or not connected like in 1) or 1a) you could use an **optocoupler** to do the switching. The input of the optocoupler is simply a LED which you can switch on/off from the Netduino. The output of the optocoupler has a transistor that starts to conduct when the LED is on. So you can simply connect the optocoupler's output to the key's button contacts. Optionally you can replace the 3 V lithium battery supply with the 3.3 V supply from the Netduino (9 out of 10 times that simply works).

Answer (score 0):

Use a solid state relay like this: -

[image]

This is just one of many types you could use - it's the G3VM-41AY1 from OMRON and quite readily available for less than £2. Internally they convert light to voltage to drive two back-to-back FETs like this: -

[image]

Make sure you pick one with low capacitance across the output mosfets. Omron make them with very low capacitance (less than 10 pF).